# Chef template render nested object

Tags: chef-infra, chef-template

I am trying to render a yaml object in chef template it is working fine but as we know in yaml spaces also matters so it is creating new properties.

```
collection: <%= @collection.to_hash.to_yaml %>
```

Where collection is a json object

```
collection = { "name": "col1", "nested": { "nKey": 1 } }
```

Expected result is

```
collection:
  name: col1
  nested:
    nKey: 1
```

Getting result

```
collection: ---
  name: col1
nested: !ruby/hash:Mash #nested is not part of collection.
  nKey: 1
```

And second is there any way to remove types(`!ruby/hash:Mash`) and `---` from to_yaml function ?

Comment: I am not sure about your use case. I think the best would be using file resource with to_yaml output as a content (instead of the template). As for Mash comment, you have to run the nested to_hash conversion, your data is probably coming from a node object, not a json. `---` could be gsub'ed(?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have one role from chef server. Then based on that role i want to render a template. everything is working fine except nested object. this is my whole use-case. instead of making nested properties it is making straight properties as I showed in my code example.

Answer (score 0):

You usually want to use `to_json`, since all JSON is valid YAML. It's a bit ugly, but usually works better :)

Comment: Sorry its not working for me. i tried both options `collection: <%= @collection.to_json %>` and `collection: <%= @collection.to_json.to_yaml %>`. to_josn is giving only json but i need YAML file. so it is creating only one string line which is `collection: --- '{ "name": "col1", "nested": { "nKey": 1 } }' %>` which is not useful in yaml file :-( Thank you

Comment: That is fine in a YAML file. As I said, it's ugly but works. YAML is a superset of JSON.